# Trying to create 2 cut off corners with linear-gradient

Tags: css

I was able to accomplish a small cutoff in the lower left hand of a box using:

```
background: linear-gradient(
  45deg,
  transparent 7px,
  $color--background 7px
);
```

But now I'm trying to create the same thing but this time 2 cut off corners in the upper left, and right.  I tried doing this, thinking it would cut off the upper left and bottom left but that didn't work out:

```
background: linear-gradient(
  45deg,
  transparent 7px,
  $color--background 7px
), linear-gradient(
  135deg,
  transparent 7px,
  $color--background 7px
);
```

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: because every background you make covers the entire box, causing the adjacent corners to become filled.

Comment: @Laif ahh okay that makes sense and at least gives me a hint in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider `background-size` and `background-position`:

```css
.box {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 20px, red 0) right, 
   linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent 20px, red 0) left;
  background-size:51% 100%; /* width height */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Or like below:

```css
.box {
  background: 
   linear-gradient( 45deg,  transparent 20px, red 0) bottom, 
   linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent 20px, red 0) top;
  background-size:100% 51%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

For a more fancy way you can consider using `mask` and have any kind of background

```css
.box {
  -webkit-mask: 
   linear-gradient( 45deg,  transparent 20px, red 0) bottom, 
   linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent 20px, red 0) top;
  -webkit-mask-size:100% 51%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  mask: 
   linear-gradient( 45deg,  transparent 20px, red 0) bottom, 
   linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent 20px, red 0) top;
  mask-size:100% 51%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  background:linear-gradient(25deg,red,yellow,purple,blue);
  height:100px;
}

.box2 {
  -webkit-mask: 
   linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 20px, red 0) right, 
   linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent 20px, red 0) left;
  -webkit-mask-size:51% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  mask: 
   linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 20px, red 0) right, 
   linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent 20px, red 0) left;
  mask-size:51% 100%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  background:linear-gradient(25deg,red,yellow,purple,blue);
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box2">
</div>
```

Comment: nice it worked!  i gotta figure out how and why background-size works with this though.  thank you

Comment: @user1189352 by default a gradient will cover all the area (100% 100%) so you need to specify a size if you don't want to simply have overlapping gradient

Comment: what happens if i wanted to change this to the upper left and upper right corners like i originally wanted?  I'm trying to fiddle with what you answered but it's quite difficult lol.  thank you regardless

Comment: @user1189352 the first snippet of my answer is doing upper right and upper left

Comment: sorry i'm still trying to understand this.. if i wanted to make 3 cut off edges.. i'm trying to play with the background-size but it's not working.  i kinda see what it's doing with the width and height.. but if i were to to use 3 linear-gradients of -135deg right, 135deg left, 135deg bottom... i feel like there's no way i can align them all up with just 2 values of background-size?  i tried putting 3 percentages for background-size but that seemed to make it worse.  thanks for any help

Comment: i think it likes the syntax of background-size:50% 90%, 50% 90%, 90% 90%; better but i guess there's no way to really rearrange it so that it can fit 3 linear gradients arranged like that all together?  anyway i give up lol.  thank you

Comment: @user1189352 try this: https://jsfiddle.net/eLu6j3rb/ better change the color of each gradient so you an understand the trick. See them like images and it would be easy

Comment: wow you really understand your linear-gradients... i was messing with it on jsbin for a good solid hour.  thank you